# Does the half-level modifier contribute to a push?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-4e-character-builder

I have a level 9 Swordmage and I just got *Forceful Dismissal*.  One question I had about it was the push part: "push the target a number of squares equal to your Strength modifier."
Does that strength modifier include my half-level bonus?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

The half-level bonus is for attacks, defenses, initiative, and skill/ability checks. It does *not* apply to anything else, and especially not to damage or forced movement distances.

Comment: And to further clarify, Strength Mod refers to your strength stat -10, /2 rounded down. Strength Check refers to strength mod + 1/2 level bonus.

Comment: As an addendum, initiative also uses half-level.

Comment: @DarkAlf Good catch, fixed. Little oversights like that are what happen when you write answers without access to the books.